# Inline editing in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

I want to implement Inline editing in Angular JS but following code is not working.

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees" ng-include="getTemplate(employee)">
                    <script type="text/ng-template" id="display">
                    <td>{{employee.Name}}</td>
                    <td ng-bind="employee.Age"></td>
                    <td ng-bind="employee.City"></td>
                    <td><a href="#" ng-click="EditEmployee(employee.EmpId)">Edit</a> </td>
                    <td><a href="#" ng-click="DeleteEmployee(employee.EmpId)">Delete</a> </td>
</script>


                    <script type="text/ng-template" id="edit">
    <td><input type="hidden" ng-model="newemployee.EmpId" class="form-control input-sm"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="newemployee.Name" class="form-control input-sm"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="newemployee.Age" class="form-control input-sm"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="newemployee.City" class="form-control input-sm"/></td>
    <td>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateEmployee(employee)">Save</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="reset()">Cancel</button>
    </td>
                    </script>
                </tr>
```

The following code is not getting called-

```
$scope.employees = [];
$scope.getTemplate = function (employee) {
        if (employee.empId === $scope.selected.empId){
            return 'edit';
        }
        else return 'display';
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ngInclude` directive is mainly used to include chunks of HTML into your page. I'm not sure you really need it here.

You could maybe simply do :

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees" {{getTemplate(employee)}}">
```

or add these labels onto the class attribute if you prefer :

```
 <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees" class="{{getTemplate(employee)}}">
```

Comment: I am taking help from following link
[link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/shubham0987/creating-simple-inline-editing-with-angularjs/)